# IE6 forms: focus disabled on input fields? (Multiple IEs after IE8)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I recently installed IE8, and found quirks using the old copies of IE I have for testing sites with. After reinstalling the "Multiple IEs" I use, I find that now I cannot focus on input fields, either with the keyboard or mouse.

I've found that other people have experienced this behavior, but not a solution for it. Has anyone here got any advice?

**EDIT:**

By 'Multiple IE versions' I mean [this](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) package and, lately, [this](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm). But I have the same problem with both. I can read the 'not supported anymore' disclaimer, but still, this is much easier and less resource-consuming than virtualization. If it worked, which it did up to a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I've had this problem too but couldn't find a reliable way to reproduce it.  Also had it reported from customers who only have IE6 installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by *reinstalling the "Multiple IEs" I use* you are referring to installing multiple copies of Internet Explorer on the same Windows instance, I'll point out that it is an unsupported configuration and can lead to all sorts of problems, including the one you are describing.

Even dual booting more than one Windows instance on the same hard disk can present problems since they all write to C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer.

The solution is to download [Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=28C97D22-6EB8-4A09-A7F7-F6C7A1F000B5&displaylang=en) (a free download). Then download one or more [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en). As of this writing, the XP images expire August 31, 2009 (the Vista images expire 120 days after first run), but Microsoft has been providing updated images whenever the previous ones expire for a couple of years now. And just today I discovered that even after the expiry date, the XP images continue to work for an hour at a time, which should provide you with time enough for testing.

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I find it so sad that this ordeal is necessary to test websites... Particularly when there's absolutely no problem doing this with the competition.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of form selects not dropping down is fixed in the latest version of Internet Explorer Collection.

What's New in Internet Explorer Collection 1.5.0.0:
- Fixed a bug which made it impossible to enter anything in input and textarea fields in IE5 up to IE7 when IE8 was installed

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. I uninstall MultipleIEs in my computer and go to C:\Program Files\MultipleIEs\IE6 and open iexplore.exe to run it again. Some registry value make the input is unselectable.