# What makes IE6 not accept text in input boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6, yui

I have 2 input boxes that are not disabled. When either gets focus no cursor is displayed and any text that you type in is not displayed. There are several events attached to these elements, but there are no js errors. Expected behavior occurs in IE7, IE8, FF2, FF3, Chrome, and Safari.

EDIT:
Here is a code example of the events being attached. Note that I am using YUI 2.

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(searchInputTop, 'focus', searchInputOnFocus);
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(searchInputTop, 'blur', searchInputOnBlur);
searchInputOnBlur = function (e) 
{   
    if (e) 
    {   
        target = (e.target || e.srcElement);
    }   
    if (target && !target.value || target.value === "") 
    {   
        target.value = someDefault;
    }   
    target.className = 'someclass';
};  

searchInputOnFocus = function(e)
{   
    if (e) 
    {   
        target = (e.target || e.srcElement);
    }   
    if (target.value === currentDefaultText)
    {   
        target.value = ""; 
    }   
    target.className = "";
};
```

UPDATE:

I don't think any of my code has anything to do with it. Any page that I view in IE6 that has input boxes has the same behavior. I'm running IE6 by using Multiple IE's under Virtual box with Win Xp service pack 3.

Comment: Please post some code that illustrates this issue.

Comment: You said that several events are attached? Could you display some code?
Even if no javascript errors occurs the scripts could still mess things up.
There are some javascript methods and attributes that won't work as supposed in IE 6, though they are still there so they won't generate an error.

Comment: Have you looked at it yet using FireBug?

Comment: csl and Jonas B code posted. 

wcm: yes I have. Nothing suspicious. It works in FF. I also do not get a js error in IE.

Comment: Only a moron would still be using IE6 anyway, so who cares?

Comment: Josh: While that may be a valid point, it doesn't matter to me. Although I don't use IE6 some people do and it is not an option at this time to not support it. I really wish we could stop supporting it, but we can't. :(

Comment: Running multiple IEs is always a bad idea - the technique used at system level to get them all working is an undocumented hack which can run into many potential problems. Run multiple virtual machines instead, each with a different version of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in MultipleIE itself.

Here: [IE6 forms: focus disabled on input fields? (Multiple IEs after IE8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829665/ie6-forms-focus-disabled-on-input-fields-multiple-ies-after-ie8)

someone suggested to uninstall MultipleIE and then try to access the files through Program Files (the files remain after the uninstall).

Another way to do it is installing "Internet Explorer Collection" instead of MultipleIE's.

(http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm)

Hope this solves your issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same problem too. In my case it didn't even matter on which website I was, there wasn't a single textbox where I could enter text...

Comment: This seems to be the same problem I am having as well. It doesn't seem to be a code issue like I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

One likely explanation is that IE is stretching some transparent element such that it covers the input fields, due to one of its many weird CSS and layout bugs. Use a DOM inspector such as the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar) to see if something is overlaid on them.

*(I've linked to the Wikipedia page for the product as that's got a better chance of staying at the same URL for a while than one of those weird microsoft.com URLS with a thirty-two-digit hexadecimal number after it. The link to today's location for the download page on microsoft.com is at the bottom.)*

Comment: That is not the case. This is happening on every page. I don't think it has anything to do with the code. It is probably my setup, but I am unsure.

Comment: Yup, it sounds like the multiple IEs - I've known other people to have had problems with them.